# Switching rows with columns in 2D array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, swap

So I am trying to figure out how to swap an ith row with the jth column. I have searched everywhere and still cant find a solution similar to what im looking for. (Pretty much switching the first row with the second column) I assume that i am going to have to create a temp to hold the value then swap it, but i can only do it for swapping out a row with another row or column with another column. At this point i am just completely lost. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

what it might look like for better clarification

Input:

```
2 3 4  
1 2 3  
4 5 6
```

Output:

```
     3    2    5
     1    3    3
     4    4    6
```

Code :

```
private int n;

private int [][] Matrix = new int[n][n];

public void switchRowColumn(int i, int j)

{

    for(int i=0; i< Matrix.length; i++)

{
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this working, see if it works for you ...

```
public class Swap{

public static void main(String[]args){
    int [][] array = {
            {2,3,4},
            {1,2,3},
            {4,5,6}
            };

    swap(array, 0 , 1);
}
public static void swap ( int [][] array, int row, int col){
    int [] temprow = new int [array[0].length];
    int [] tempcol = new int [array.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++) {
            if(i == row){
                temprow = array[i]; // TEMP ROW
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++) {
            if(j == col){
                tempcol[i] = array[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < tempcol.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(tempcol[i]); /// COLS
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            if(i == row){
                array[i] = tempcol;
            }
        }
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++) {
            if(j == col){
                array[i][j] = temprow[i];
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println();

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(array[i][j]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

}